# spring configuring embedded BrokerService

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

i would like to configure embedded ActiveMQ broker service inside spring mvc application.

Here is my configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfiguration {

@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public BrokerService brokerService() throws Exception {
    BrokerService brokerService = new BrokerService();
    brokerService.setPersistent(false);
    brokerService.setUseJmx(false);
    brokerService.addConnector("vm://localhost:0");
    brokerService.setBrokerName("broker");
    brokerService.setUseShutdownHook(false);
    return brokerService;
}
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
    return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost:0");
}

@Bean
public ActiveMQQueue defaultDestination(){
    return new ActiveMQQueue("broker");
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(defaultDestination());
    return jmsTemplate;
}
}
```

and simple test get request to send message to broker service 
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

```
@Autowired
public TestController(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate){
    this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/test/jms", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String SendJMSMsg(Locale locale){
    try {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("test");
        return "OK";
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();

    }
}
```

jmsTemplate.convertAndSend throws this exception

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisorySupport.isVirtualDestinationConsumerAdvisoryTopic(Lorg/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQDestination;)Z
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:497)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:569)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:560)
    at si.lapps.fabijan.controller.AdminController.SendJMSMsg(AdminController.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisorySupport.isVirtualDestinationConsumerAdvisoryTopic(Lorg/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQDestination;)Z
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1401)
    at org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer.<init>(AdvisoryConsumer.java:51)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1513)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:324)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:485)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisorySupport.isVirtualDestinationConsumerAdvisoryTopic(Lorg/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQDestination;)Z
    at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.addConsumer(AdvisoryBroker.java:205)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConsumer(BrokerFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConsumer(BrokerFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConsumer(MutableBrokerFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConsumer(TransportConnection.java:671)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerInfo.visit(ConsumerInfo.java:351)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:338)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:188)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onCommand(ResponseCorrelator.java:116)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.iterate(VMTransport.java:271)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
```

Can someone help me with this problem? If i use external ActiveMQ work all fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original problem with exception was solved with Adrey Brown answer but my listener doesn't receive any messages. What is wrong with my configuration

This is my bean configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@ComponentScan("si.xxxx.yyyyy.jms")
public class JmsConfiguration{

    @Bean//(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public BrokerService brokerService() throws Exception {
        BrokerService brokerService = new BrokerService();
        brokerService.setPersistent(false);
        brokerService.setUseJmx(false);
        //brokerService.addConnector("vm://localhost:0");
        brokerService.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
        brokerService.setBrokerName("broker");
        brokerService.setUseShutdownHook(false);
        return brokerService;
    }
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        factory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQQueue defaultDestination(){
        return new ActiveMQQueue("email");
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(defaultDestination());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer containerFactory = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        containerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        containerFactory.setDestination(defaultDestination());
        containerFactory.setMessageListener(messageListener());
        return containerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListener messageListener(){
        return new MessageListener();
    }
}
```

sender

```
@Service
public class MessageSender {

    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public MessageSender(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate){
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void sendUserConfirmationEmail(NewUserMessage message){
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(message);
    }
}
```

and listener
    @Service
    public class MessageListener implements javax.jms.MessageListener{

```
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage)message;
        try {
            if (objectMessage.getObject() instanceof NewUserMessage) {
                NewUserMessage newUserMessage = (NewUserMessage) objectMessage.getObject();
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing comment from @Bean//(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop") solved problem

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and it turned out to be some dependency management within one of the activemq jars that forced `activemq-client` down to a version that did not contain `AdvisorySupport.isVirtualDestinationConsumerAdvisoryTopic`. In my case the desired `5.13.2` was being downgraded to `5.12.2`.

My `build.gradle` contained this:

```
compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.13.2'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-stomp:5.13.2'
```

and the dependencies were:

```
+--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.13.2
|    +--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.13.2 -> 5.12.2
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10 -> 1.7.13
|    |    +--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|    |    +--- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:1.11
|    |    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:1.0.1
|    \--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-openwire-legacy:5.13.2 -> 5.12.2
|         \--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.12.2 (*)
\--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-stomp:5.13.2
     \--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.13.2 (*)
```

What fixed it for me was to specify the activemq client version in `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.13.2'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.13.2'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-stomp:5.13.2'
```

The dependencies now look like:

```
+--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.13.2
|    +--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.13.2
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
|    |    +--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|    |    +--- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:1.11
|    |    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:1.0.1
|    \--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-openwire-legacy:5.13.2 -> 5.12.2
|         \--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.12.2 -> 5.13.2 (*)
+--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.13.2 (*)
\--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-stomp:5.13.2
     \--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.13.2 (*)
```

and the error no longer happens.

**Important note**: The activemq project owners will have done that dependency management for a reason (I suspect it's to do with the `org.apache.activemq:activemq-openwire-legacy` project) so be ready to fix any compatibility issues that come up.